# The best way to read binary data from .dat file and reverse a binary value C#

Tags: c#, binary

I have a .dat file with formatted in binary. This .dat file contains a blacklisted value with presented ones as true and zeroes as false. When opened with notepad or notepad++, I can't see the zeroes and ones inside. Only the strange character shows.

Example :

> ù¿.ÿôý½¯ÿËûþÿÅ}ó

But I have download the hex editor, with that software I can see the hex value. The value is

> F9 BF 7F FF F4 FD BD AF FF CB FB FE FF C5 7D F3

For each hex value, I need to change in binary format. So let's say for **F9**, when we change to binary it will become **11111001** and for **BF** it will be **10111111** and so on.

So in the binary value, I need to reverse on every binary digit then save it to database.Let say current value is **11111001**, then I will got **10011111** and every binary digit will store to database. Same as **10111111** and so on. So in database table, for **F9** it will become

```
id    flag_blacklist  
1         1       
2         0       
3         0       
4         1       
5         1            
6         1
7         1
8         1
```

And continue for value **BF** it will becomes

```
id    flag_blacklist  
9         1
10        1
11        1
12        1
13        1
14        1
15        0
16        1
```

Until finish read all the contains in .dat file.

The flow is **Hex value** > **Binary Value** > **Reverse Binary Digit** > **Store to database**

After Google a few hours, I still not found the best answer and suited with my case. If have any link can help me to solved this problems or required more informations, please let me knows.

### Edited :

The maximum size of .dat files is 245 KB.

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with Windows Forms... there's nothing in your question which is GUI-specific at all.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Let's me check and give the updates

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry due accidentally tags the winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to read the file as a byte array and reverse the bit order for each byte.

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("file.dat");
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = ReverseBits(data[i]);
}
// Now write data to the database, however you want to.
```

where the `ReverseBits` method can be be written in a "naive but reasonably easy to understand" way as:

```
private static byte ReverseBits(byte value)
{
    // Just mask out each bit in turn and work out where it should end up.
    return (byte) (((value & 0x01) << 7) |
                   ((value & 0x02) << 5) |
                   ((value & 0x04) << 3) |
                   ((value & 0x08) << 1) |
                   ((value & 0x10) >> 1) |
                   ((value & 0x20) >> 3) |
                   ((value & 0x40) >> 5) |
                   ((value & 0x80) >> 7)));
}
```

... or you could use that naive way to build a 256-element lookup table, then use that when you're processing the bytes.

Comment: Yes this I looking for, but it take more than 1 minutes to read all the values in .dat files with 245kb of sizes. Any suggestions to improves the performance?

Comment: @Chuki2: Is that under a debugger or not? Have you measured how much of that time is spent 1) reading the file; 2) reversing the bytes; 3) uploading to the database? I suspect it's almost all in the third step, unless the file is on a network share.

Comment: Which file reads fast `.DAT or .TXT or .APPCONFIG` ? actually i want to save a integer variable in a file , so that i can access it in asp mvc application globally.

Comment: @stom: It sounds like you should be asking a new question, and it should be a *lot* clearer than that. Why would you need a file just to have an integer value anyway? Don't reply as a comment: ask a new question, after reading https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/